# How to use colorRamp in ggplot for a pie chart?

Tags: ggplot2, data-visualization, pie-chart, color-scheme, colorbrewer

I am trying to make a pie chart using ggplot2.

So far I have been successful, except for the color component. I am trying to use `colorRamp::primary.colors` because the items in my chart are categorical, so gradient colors blurred the boundaries between each item. I tried `R brewer`, but it doesn't have enough color.

[image: pie chart]

https://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/~frazier/RSpatialGuides/colorPaletteCheatsheet.pdf

I am not sure how to add colorRamp to my code. Should create a list of color first and then add it to ggplot?

```
winter <- structure(list(site = c("CI", "CI", "CI", "CI", "CI", "CI", "CI", 
"CI", "PI", "PI", "PI", "PI", "MF", "MF", "MF", "MF", "MF", "MF", 
"MF", "LK", "LK", "LK", "LK", "LK", "LK", "LK", "MF", "MF", "MF", 
"MF", "MF", "BL", "BL", "BL", "BL", "BL", "BL", "BL", "BL", "BL", 
"BL", "BL", "BL", "LP", "LP", "LP", "LP", "LP", "LP", "LP", "LP", 
"NP", "NP", "NP", "NP", "NP", "NP", "NP", "TC", "TC", "TC", "TC", 
"TC", "TC", "SO", "BI", "WI", "WI", "WI"), alga = c("Plocamium", 
"Colpomenia", "Hypnea", "Ulva", "Colpomenia", "Dictyota", "S. hemiphyllum", 
"Ulva", "Colpomenia", "Dictyota (small)", "S. hemiphyllum", "Ulva", 
"Colpomenia", "Colpomenia", "Corallina", "Dictyota (small)", 
"Gelidium", "S. hemiphyllum", "Ulva", "Colpomenia", "Dictyota (big)", 
"Dictyota (small)", "Plocamium", "Pockiela", "S. hemiphyllum", 
"S.tenerrimum", "Colpomenia", "Corallina", "Padina", "S. hemiphyllum", 
"Ulva", "Colpomenia", "Dictyota (big)", "Dictyota (small)", "Dictosphaesia", 
"Plocamium", "Pockiela", "Cladophora", "Corallina", "Gelidium", 
"Gigartina", "S. hemiphyllum", "Ulva", "Codium", "Colpomenia", 
"Ulva", "Colpomenia", "Gelidium", "Gigartina", "S. hemiphyllum", 
"Ulva", "Colpomenia", "Colpomenia", "Gelidium", "Gigartina", 
"S. hemiphyllum", "S.tenerrimum", "Ulva", "Colpomenia", "Ulva", 
"Colpomenia", "Dictyota (big)", "S. hemiphyllum", "Ulva", "Ulva", 
"Colpomenia", "Colpomenia", "S. hemiphyllum", "Ulva"), kg = c(0.00209, 
0.84109, 0.00746, 0.05966, 0.01617, 0.00189, 27.37882, 1.61209, 
1.5998, 0.00969, 6.89784, 0.00049, 0.23829, 2.4064, 0.00608, 
0.01422, 0.01735, 2.55, 0.11174, 0.68972, 1.22544, 0.01607, 0.00719, 
0.00044, 0.35, 0.00401, 0.23829, 0.83879, 0.2129, 1.9627, 0.00157, 
0.02963, 0.03386, 0.49223, 5e-04, 0.04417, 1.61504, 0.00121, 
0.06069, 0.00944, 0.4431, 5.35, 0.3, 0.00963, 0.35527, 0.00257, 
0.74142, 0.06269, 0.20287, 30.7, 0.02773, 0.02052, 0.01596, 0.0467, 
0.01082, 21.92626, 0.09068, 0.24969, 0.09909, 0.00143, 0.1968, 
1.10294, 4.85, 0.10844, 4.1, 1.97947, 0.00358, 13.52087, 0.01678
)), row.names = c(NA, -69L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

library(ggplot2)
library(colorRamps)
weight <- ggplot(winter, aes(x = "", y = kg, fill = alga)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity")

pie <- weight + 
  coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
  colorRampPalette(primary.colors(17), no.white = TRUE) #this is where I am stuck
pie
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first: [**Don't do pie charts!!**](https://blog.funnel.io/why-we-dont-use-pie-charts-and-some-tips-on-better-data-visualizations)

---

[w/o looking at your data i did not even realize in the first place that there are more points per `alga`, which is nicely visible int eh point chart below and what was not visible in the bar/pie chart)

To solve the problem of having more categories than brewer colors, you can easily fall back on `colorRampPalette`:

```
library(RColorBrewer)

my_pal <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, "Set1"))

weights <- ggplot(winter, 
                  aes(x = reorder(alga, kg, max), 
                      y = kg, 
                      color = reorder(alga, kg, max))) +
           geom_point() + coord_flip()


weights + scale_color_manual("", values = my_pal(nlevels(as.factor(winter$alga))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! One thing: I am not sure what `max` stands for in the `reorder` brackets.

Comment: Actually it takes a factor and a numeric value, then it applies the function (in this case `max`) to all the numeric values to summarize it down to one value (again in this case `max`) then it reorders the factor levels according to the values of this summary function. That is, the `alga` which has the `max` `kg` will come first.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. To further visualise the data, I used `geom_boxplot` instead of `geom_point` so I can see the average and all of that. Much appreciate your help on this.